# update a div data dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, pageload

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {                               
                ResetEmpNominee();               
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt32(ddlEmployee.SelectedValue) > 0)
        {  
              populateTrainingInfo(Convert.ToInt16(ddlEmployee.SelectedValue));
        }
    }


protected void btnTrainingSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            short empID = 0;
            if (empID =0)
            {
                success = hrServer.addToEmpTraining(trainingNew, path);
                if (success.Equals("Success"))
                {
                    Msg = "Successfully Added...";                    }
                else
                {
                    Msg = success;
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }

            WebUtil.jsCall("alert('" + Msg + "')", this);


            Page_Load(null, null); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WebUtil.MessageBox_Show(ex.Message, this);
        }

    }





private void populateTrainingInfo(short empID)
    {
        HumanResourceServer hrServer = new HumanResourceServer();
        DataSet trainingInfoes = hrServer.GetEmployeeTrainingInfo(empID);
        int i = 0;
        int count = trainingInfoes.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        ViewState["TrainingInfo"] = trainingInfoes.Tables[0];
        int k = 0;
        DataTable dtTraining = trainingInfoes.Tables[0];
        for (i = 0; i < dtTraining.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //first row
            Table tblTraining = new Table();
            tblTraining.Width = 900;
            TableCell tcLeft1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tcRight1 = new TableCell();
            TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();
            tr1.CssClass = "cvItemSubHeader";
            Label lblHeader1 = new Label();
            lblHeader1.ID = "Training" + Convert.ToString(i + 1);
            lblHeader1.Text = "Training :" + Convert.ToString(i + 1);
            tcLeft1.CssClass = "cvColumnCaption";
            //tcLeft1.CssClass = "cvItemButtonCell";
            tcLeft1.Controls.Add(lblHeader1);
            tcLeft1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
            Button btnTrainingEdit = new Button();
            btnTrainingEdit.ID = "btnTrainingEdit" + Convert.ToString(i + 1);
            btnTrainingEdit.Text = "Edit";
            btnTrainingEdit.CssClass = "DSEButton4";

            //Label lblHeader2 = new Label();
            //lblHeader2.ID = "LevelofEducationData" + Convert.ToString(i);
            //lblHeader2.Text = dtTraining.Rows[i]["EDUCATIONLEVELNAME"].ToString();
            tcRight1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            //tcRight1.Style["Padding-left"] ="50";
            tcRight1.CssClass = "cvItemButtonCell";
            tcRight1.Controls.Add(btnTrainingEdit);




            tr1.Cells.Add(tcLeft1);
            tr1.Cells.Add(tcRight1);
            tblTraining.Rows.Add(tr1);


            btnTrainingEdit.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnTrainingEdit_click);
            tcRight1.Controls.Add(btnTrainingEdit);
            tr1.Cells.Add(tcLeft1);
            tr1.Cells.Add(tcRight1);
            tblTraining.Rows.Add(tr1);

            //hidden row for educationid

            tcLeft1 = new TableCell();
            tcRight1 = new TableCell();
            tr1 = new TableRow();

            tr1.CssClass = "hiddenDynamicRows";

            lblHeader1 = new Label();
            lblHeader1.ID = "TRAININGID" + Convert.ToString(i + 1);
            lblHeader1.Text = "TRAININGID";

            tcLeft1.CssClass = "cvColumnCaption";
            tcLeft1.Controls.Add(lblHeader1);
            tcLeft1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;


            Label lblHeader2 = new Label();
            lblHeader2.ID = "TRAININGIDData" + Convert.ToString(i + 1);
            lblHeader2.Text = dtTraining.Rows[i]["TRAININGID"].ToString();

            tcRight1.Controls.Add(lblHeader2);


            tr1.Cells.Add(tcLeft1);
            tr1.Cells.Add(tcRight1);
            tblTraining.Rows.Add(tr1);
            Trainings.Controls.Add(tblTraining);
        }
        count = trainingInfoes.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    }
```

aspx page contain some following code

```
<table class="contentRow"  width="900px">
                         <tr     class="cvItemHeader" align="left">
                           <td align="left" >
                                 <div><div    class="cvItemHeaderText"> Training Summary </div>
                               <div class="cvItemHeaderButton">
                                                                     <asp:Button ID="btnAddTraining" runat="server" CssClass="DSEButton4" 
                                                                         Text="Add" onclick="btnAddTrainingInfo_Click" /> </div>                     
                                   </div>
                             </td>

                    </tr>

           <div id="Trainings" runat="server"></div>

                                                </table>
```

Sorry, for my unclear question. btnTrainingSave_Click method save data into database. I need to update the div with id='Trainings' after saving the data into database. I called page_load method at the end of btnTrainingSave_Click method. But it does not work. can anybody help me how can I do that? Perhaps this time my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the concept is wrong, to refresh the page redirect to the same URL

```
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
```

Comment: my question was not right. would u please have a look now

Comment: The concept still wrong. if there is couple lines of code that you want to call in page load and anywhere else, you can create a function with this lines and call them anywhere you want.

Comment: I need to call populateTrainingInfo to update div id Trainings  after btnTrainingSave button is clicked. I have tried to call populateTrainingInfo at the end of the btnTrainingSave_Click method But It also does not update the div id Trainings. How can I update div id Trainings.

Comment: is there any updatepannel in your code?

Comment: yes, the aspx code I mention is within the updatepannel.

Comment: this is the problem, the content is not updated as there is an updatepannel check this link, it might help http://forums.asp.net/t/1125367.aspx?Using+Updatepanel+to+update+html+content+of+DIV+element+

Comment: yes you are right, I have checked it. I put the code outside update panel and its working now. Now the problem is I have a dropdownlist in my application. I also need to reload the data to update div content with id Trainings on selectedintexchange of that dropdownlist. Now where I need to put the aspx code so that div content update both according to the selectedindexchange and btnTrainingSave_Click.

Comment: sorry, previous comment is not correct.I put the code outside update panel and its not working

Comment: can you remove the update pannel from the page and give it a try, if every thing is working fine, then you need to isolate the needed actions from the updatepannel, or you can try to use JavaScript to add html in the page, but first confirm that every thing is working when you remove the updatepannel form the markup

Comment: Ok, I am doing so. In the mean time I am telling the whole scenario what I need. If u could give me any easy suggestion, I have one dropdown list and a div id training. The div content is one or more training info of a person. when the person in dropdown change the div content is changed with training information with a edit button for each information to edit training information. I have a ModalPopup page to save training information. I also need to update the div content when new information is saved. This is what is exactly needed.

Comment: looks like it is better to update the div content in HTML using JavaScript, as i understand, there is no make the change on server side

Comment: Thanks, after removing update panel I got an error message and it was  duplicate ID. after solving it. the system working fine both with and without updatepanel.